# Is it possible to sort using sorted() with attributes from two different models?

Tags: python, django, sorting, model

I'm trying to sort a list of posts where votes have priority over the date.

I have my own app called UserPost and I'm using the django-voting app to do votes.

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vote = models.ForeignKey(Vote)
```

Right now, I'm sorting without votes taking precedence yet:

```
posts_list = sorted(posts_list, key=attrgetter('datetime'))
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick tip: you should use `posts_list.sort(key=attrgetter('datetime'))` instead of using the `sorted` built-in function. The `sorted` function will create a copy of the list, while the `sort` method of a list sorts the list in-place and is slightly faster (and uses approximately half as much memory).

Comment: @mlefavor: I doubt that sorting will be much of a bottleneck, unless you have a list with more than a million elements. Use whatever is most readable for the situation, worry about performance later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are sorted lexicographically, therefore if you return a tuple for sorted's key= argument you can sort by votes then by dates:

```
posts_list = sorted(posts_list, key=lambda post: (Vote.objects.get_score(post)['score'], post.datetime))
```

Alternatively, you might want to also look at the `ordering` option in a django Model's Meta class or the `order_by` method on django Queryset. They will do the sorting on the database in one query, so can be much faster. Alternatively, you can try the posts_list.get_score_in_bulk() to reduce the number of queries to two (one for posts_list, and one for get_score_in_bulk), like so:

```
scores = Vote.objects.get_score_in_bulk(posts_list)
posts_list = sorted(posts_list, key=lambda post: (scores[post.id]['score'], post.datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it like that:

```
def posts_sorting(post1, post2):
    # put here the way you compare posts
    pass # return 1 if post2 before post1, -1 otherwise, 0 if they are "equal"

posts_list = sorted(posts_list, cmp=posts_sorting)
```

where `posts_sorting` is the function that compares your posts.